# How to know if mysql tmpdir is being used

Tags: mysql, configuration

I set my MySQL `tmpdir` setting to use `/run/mysqld` which is a `tmpfs`, however while running a query I *know* copies data to a temp table (which takes 5-6 seconds based on MySQL's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILE` records) I am not seeing any temporary file(s) being written out to that directory when doing an `ls -la` at the command prompt.

Additionally, the query speed did not change when moving my tmpdir from an on-disk location to an in memory location (tmpfs) which it clearly should have improved.

**Question:** How do I know for sure that my tmpdir is being used?

Answer (score 2):

In *nix, a file can be creat'd, rm'd, *then* written to and read from by the *same* process.  No flavor of `ls` can see it, since it is already rm'd from the directory, yet the program can see it.  This is a trick that makes sure that the file is not left behind if the program crashes.  [*MySQL often uses the rm trick*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-files.html).

`ls` cannot see the rm'd-but-not-closed files, but `lsof` can see them as `(deleted)`.

`df` will change because of the space being consumed.

If you show us the `SELECT`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT`.  We may be able to give you tips on avoiding the tmp table.  (I assume your *real question* is about performance?)

Comment: Yes, [MySQL often uses that trick](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-files.html), and `lsof` should show them.  The files will show in the list as `(deleted)`.  `df` will show the space change.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Thanks. I folded your comment in; your comment can be removed.  Note: now a community wiki.